# How to interpret this information in probability?

Tags: probability, word-problem

Given a sentence "in a jar full of marbles, 10 percent of black marbles are plastic"

Suppose $A$ is the event of being a black marble and $B$ the event of being plastic.
How should I interpret this information?
There are two ways I could think to interpret the information, first the probability of both being a black marble and a plastic marble is $10/100$.
The other way I could interpret it is the probability of a ball being plastic given it's a black ball is $10/100$
I can't tell which one is appropriate.

Is it
$$
\mathbb{P}(A \cap B)=\frac{10}{100}
\quad \text{or} \quad
\mathbb{P}(B |A)=\frac{10}{100}?$$

Comment: Well, what does $P(A\cap B)$ represent? What does $P(B\mid A)$ represent? This seems like a HW problem, you need to show some effort on your part.

Comment: @DonThousand Arguable.  This question borders on an interpretation question.  While others *will* disagree, I question the appropriateness of asking the original poster to show work, when the question being asked is an interpretation question.

Comment: Another way of saying it is that A is the set of black marbles and B is the set of plastic marbles.  Then what is $A\cap B$?

Comment: To the OP: I can't ignore the viewpoints of other mathSE reviewers and answer the question.  However, I can advise: **ignore** the math, and **stretch your intuition**.  Your question presents two options.  What does each option signify, **intuitively**?  What does the premise signify, **intuitively**?  Which option is an **intuitive** match?

Comment: $P(A \cap B)$ should be the probability of both being a black and a plastic marble. $P(B|A)$ is the probability of a marble being plastic, given it's a black marble, I can't tell the difference between the two.

Comment: What is wrong with my question, I am not asking for a solution and didn't even post a problem, I just want to know the difference between $P(B|A)$ and $P(A \cap B)$, this is about interpreting the information.

Comment: "What is wrong with my question, I am not asking for a solution and didn't even post a problem" : I absolutely agree; like I commented, your question borders on being an interpretation question.  In no way can I justify the viewpoint of other mathSE reviewers, for your question.  However, that viewpoint exists.

Comment: For better or worse, if you are guided by [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236), it will be very difficult for a mathSE reviewer to downvote your question.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

As you can see, from the table, the right answer is the second option, a conditional probability,

$$\mathbb{P}(B \vert A)=\frac{10}{100},$$

i.e.

$$\mathbb{P}(\text{plastic}\,\vert\, \text{black})=\frac{10}{100}.$$

---

*The more detail answer:*

From the assignment

> In a jar full of marbles, $10$ percent of black marbles are plastic.

we know *nothing* about the second row (“No black”), we are restricted (= conditional probability) by the *black marbles only* (“… $10$ percent of **black** marbles …”).

---

*Note:*

There is no possibility to calculate $\mathbb{P}(A \cap B)$ not knowing anything about total number of marbles (black and non-black) in a jar.

Comment: If $n$ was the total number of marbles then $P(A \cap B)=\frac{10}{n} $ am I right?

Comment: @Mason_dns, yes, you're.

Comment: @Mason_dns, your statement in your comment is true *only if 10 is the number of black plastic marbles,* as is in my table. But from your assignment it is impossible to derive the **number** of black plastic marbles, there is only a **percentage** from an *unknown* number of the black marbles.

Answer (score 0):

(b) Suppose there are 100 black marbles in the jar.
Then 10 of those black marbles are plastic.

(a) Would suppose there are 100 marbles in the jar and that 10 of them are both black and plastic. How many more are black and glass (granite, lava, marble, or whatever) is not disclosed.